# Comparing current Month and previous Month's rows on a column, SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, lead

I need some guidance and help with a question I am not entirely sure how to solve in SQL Server 2012. I think `LAG` and `LEAD` functions could be useful but I am not sure.

This is what my data looks right now:

```
=========================================
YearMonth   LocationCode    Active      
=========================================
201405      123              0  
201406      123              2  
201409      211              1
201410      211              0
201411      214              0
201412      214              3
```

We have a `YearMonth` column that shows how the status looked like for each `locationCode` and an `Active` int that represents a quality for each `LocationCode`

**Objective:**

My objective is to compare the `LocationCode` for for the current `YearMonth` (let's call it `201406`) and the previous `Yearmonth` (let's call it `201405`):

An example :

```
=========================================
YearMonth   LocationCode    Active      
=========================================
201405      123              0  
201406      123              2
```

Basically what I am trying to figure out is how to compare the current month's row (201406) to the previous month's row (201405) on the column called `Active`.

If the current month's row `Active` column is a non-zero and the previous month's Active was a zero, then we conclude the current month's row to be "New" (1) else (0).

An example is provided below:

```
==================================================
YearMonth   LocationCode    Active   New    
===================================================
201405      123              0        0 
201406      123              2        1
201409      211              1        0
201410      211              0        0
201411      214              0        0
201412      214              3        1
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I have a number of variations on ROW_NUMBER()  looking the first time the row and Active was Zero and the second row being a non-zero but it did not come correct out as in many cases. As the active can have been 1 in some month and other not, that is why I am keen on some comparision technique for just current and previous month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use a query like this:

```
SELECT *,
    CASE 
        WHEN Active <> 0 AND 
             ISNULL(LAG(Active) OVER (PARTITION BY LocationCode ORDER BY YearMonth), 0) = 0 THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 
    END As New
FROM yourTable;
```

[[SQL Fiddle Demo]](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/de523/5)

Comment: Did u test this? Looks like some conditions should be reversed.

Comment: Yes, definitely conditions should be reversed )

Comment: @Bulat Ooops I got it, Thanks ;).

Comment: no problems, I am not sure whether `new` can be set to 1 several times for same `locationcode`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `ROW_NUMBER() OVER` like this:

```
WITH RankedCodesHistory AS (
 SELECT 
   YearMonth,
   LocationCode,
   Active,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LocationCode, CASE WHEN Active > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
                    ORDER BY LocationCode, YearMonth, Active) rn
 FROM CodesHistory)
SELECT 
  YearMonth,
  LocationCode,
  Active,
  CASE WHEN Active > 0 AND rn = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS New
FROM RankedCodesHistory
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/de523/2)

I have extended your data sample in the Fiddle to demonstrate what will happen if Active goes back to zero and becomes positive second time --- in this case code above will not set corresponding row as new.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.Do you think there is a way way to implement LAG and LEAD function for this problem?Your solution is good, however the problem on my side is that I will have many million of rows. That is why I am interested in just comparing two months, the previous month's column to current month's record. I like your solution because it gave some more insight as to how I can solve other problems with your strategy. Thank you Bulat.

Comment: now @shA.t updated his answer with correct conditions, does it work for you?