# ROW_NUMBER() with BETWEEN SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, row-number

I need some guidance with using `ROW_NUMBER()` along with `BETWEEN` in SQL Server 2012.

I have written the following code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    *,
    CASE WHEN (row_number() OVER BETWEEN (PARTITION BY LocationCode 
                                          ORDER BY startdate ASC) AND EndDate) = 1 
           THEN 1 ELSE 0 
    END AS Testr,
FROM 
    Table
```

The purpose is to tag those `locationCode BETWEEN MIN(startDate) AND EndDate` with 1 ELSE 0.

How can I do that?

I have added a table : this is how it looks right now

```
LocationCode    StartDate   EndDate
10808247    20140617    20140701
10808247    20140618    20140701
10808247    20140618    20140701
10808247    20140617    20140701
10808247    20140709    20140801
```

**Objective**:

```
LocationCode    StartDate   EndDate   New
10808247    20140617    20140701            1
10808247    20140618    20140701            1
10808247    20140618    20140701            1
10808247    20140617    20140701            1
10808247    20140709    20140801            0
```

The last row for column `New` is zero because it is outside the `EndDate`.

Comment: Why would you use `ROW_NUMBER` for this?

Comment: I am not sure what other way to go to resolve the problem I have been working on since this morning. Basically, that is all I need to do. How to code it, I am finding it a bit hard.

Comment: Please include examples. Values are usually always bigger or equal to min values, and it's quite difficult to figure out what EndDate is

Comment: what are you comparing the `min(startdate)` and `enddate` with?

Comment: Classify each Location that is between the Min(StartDate) AND EndDate, then tag all those rows with 1 else 0

Comment: How can a `LocationCode` be compared to a `Date`?  That's the part I'm struggling with.

Comment: @Siyual Precisely my question.

Comment: @user3197575 How do you know that `The last row for column New... is outside the EndDate`?

Comment: I have added two tables now.

Comment: Your example even has duplicate rows, and doesn't clarify the question at all.

Comment: @FutbolFan That is the condition I have trying to create.The LocationCode should only be valid between specific StartDate and EndDate. If it is, then 1 else 0.

Comment: Looks like you asked this question already? Although it has totally different explanations... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31942653/data-manipulation-row-number-sql-server

Comment: And also this, which is again about location codes and dates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31903349/comparing-current-month-and-previous-months-rows-on-a-column-sql-server-2012

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a `ROW_NUMBER()` for this.  You can do this with a `CROSS APPLY`.

I'm assuming, based on your sample data, that the datatypes for these fields are `INT`.

```
Select  T.LocationCode, T.StartDate, T.EndDate,
        Case When T.StartDate > X.MinEndDate Then 0 Else 1 End As New
From    Table   T
Cross Apply
(
    Select  Min(T2.EndDate) MinEndDate
    From    Table   T2
    Where   T2.LocationCode = T.LocationCode
) X
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could do simple group by and join back the table like this:

```
SELECT T.LocationCode
      ,T.StartDate
      ,T.EndDate
      ,CASE 
         WHEN T.StartDate > t2.MinEndDate
            THEN 0
       ELSE 1
       END AS New
FROM test T
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT locationcode
           ,Min(EndDate) MinEndDate
    FROM test
    GROUP BY locationcode
    ) T2 ON T2.LocationCode = T.LocationCode;
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/11165/5/0)